# Only 160 TCP-Connections with 18.04

Tags: tcp

About 1000 IoT devices are sending data to my server with TCP/INETD. Everything worked fine with Ubuntu 16.04. After Upgrading to 18.04 only 160 devices can be connected.
I already increased noproc, nofiles etc - nothing changes.
I made a very simple script which only accepts the connection, waits 10 seconds and quits. No changes. Not more then 160 devices.
Is there a limit for TCP-Connections?

Answer (score 0):

From 16.04 to 18.04 has changed default of DefaultTasksMax:

16.04: 18446744073709551615

18.04: 105

Edit /etc/systemd/system.conf DefaultTasksMax=infinity or f.e. DefaultTasksMax=4000.